# Events and cursor position

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show mouse coordinates while the cursor over the red div and mouse button is down.

The problem is when i release the button outside the div and return the cursor back to the div, onmousemove event is not removed.

**NOTE: I don't want to use any library like jQuery.**

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

              window.onload = function(){

      document.getElementById("thediv").onmousedown = AttachEvent;

     }
            function GetPos(e){                                
                document.getElementById('X').value = (window.Event) ? e.pageX : event.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft);
                document.getElementById('Y').value = (window.Event) ? e.pageY : event.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop);

            }

            function UnaatachEvent(e){
                document.getElementById("thediv").onmousemove = null;
                document.getElementById("thediv").onmouseup = null;
            }

            function AttachEvent(e){
                document.getElementById("thediv").onmousemove = GetPos;
                document.getElementById("thediv").onmouseup = UnaatachEvent;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="X" size="3">X-position
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type="text" id="Y" size="3">Y-position 
        <div style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:red;margin:auto;" id="thediv">
        </div>
    </body>
```

**UPDATE:**
With jQuery it's very easy: (tested in Firefox only)
[link text](http://www.webdevout.net/test?01x&raw)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#thediv').mousedown(attachEvent);
  });  
function attachEvent(e){
       $('#thediv').mousemove(getPos).mouseup(unattachEvent);

      return false;
}

function getPos(e){

  document.getElementById('X').value = e.pageX;
  document.getElementById('Y').value = e.pageY;            
 return false;
}

function unattachEvent(e){
   $('#thediv').unbind("mousemove", getPos).unbind("mouseup", unattachEvent);
```

Please note main scenarios:

1. If button was clicked outside the square, and while holding, moved to suqre - Don't upddate position.
2. If button was clicked inside the square , and while holding, move outside - stop update, bring it back (without releasing the button) continue update

In other words, the initial mousedown should be on square only to start the update.

I want to do the same with javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code can be better written as (**[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/ojuka4/3/)**)

```
var div = document.getElementById("thediv");
div.onmousedown = attachEvent;

// if mouse released, stop watching mouseover
document.onmouseup = function () {
  div.onmouseover = null;
}

function attachEvent() {
  this.onmousemove = getPos;
  this.onmouseout  = unattachEvent;
  this.onmouseup   = unattachEvent;
  return false; // prevent Firefox "drag behavior"
}

function unattachEvent() {
  this.onmousemove = null;
  this.onmouseup   = null;
  this.onmouseout  = null;
  // wait for the mouse to come back
  this.onmouseover = attachEvent;
}

function getPos(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var docEl = document.documentElement;
  var scrollLeft = docEl.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft;
  var scrollTop  = docEl.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
  document.getElementById('X').value = e.pageX || (e.clientX  + scrollLeft);
  document.getElementById('Y').value = e.pageY || (e.clientY  + scrollTop);
}​
```

Comment: this is not good, because if I hold mouse, move it out side and then (without releasing) move it back inside I expect to get the position.

Comment: @jullin: Then you should check `onmouseover` if the left button is (still) down at reattach the event.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel , how do I check that and where?

Comment: But it's not what I need, is it?

Comment: galambalazs, i am not. please try the following: click and hold mouse while on red square, while holding move outside the square (don't release the button) the positioning is not updated (as it should be), now return cursor to the square (still holding), the positioning is not beeing updated

Comment: it's not working in firefox at all, in ie it's not working when you bring cursor back.